# Run Controller method from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

This seems easy but is not just working for me. I have the following code to run a method in my `HomeController` from my JavaScript file:

```
function(id) {
    alert("here");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/HomeController/MethodName',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(data){
             alert('Sucess ' + data);      
        }
    });
}
```

My method is

```
public string MethodName(int id)
{
    return id.ToString() + "test ";
}
```

The view calling the javascript has the following scripts defined: jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, MicrosoftAjax.js, validate.unobtrusive.min.js, jquery.validate.min.js

But is is not just working. Nothing happens. The first alert of the function do show up. But nothing else after that.

Comment: Have you had a look in Chrome tools or Firebug to make sure that the URL is being hit and returning a non-error status code?

Comment: How do I do that please? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hit F12 in Chrome and the dev tools will display at the bottom of the browser window. Click the Network tab and you can view the HTTP traffic for your site.

Comment: You're missing `{` on the first line, after `function(id)` - dunno if that's a typo, or if it will have any effect though. If it is in your code, it could be causing your function to just be `alert("here")`, which would explain your behaviour - I'm not sure what the browser might do to try to cope.

Comment: Hit F12 key and click the "Network" tab and then give it a go to see if a request is being made. You should also set a failure callback function as well to print out any possible errors. You may not see anything without that if you're getting errors.

Comment: Thank you all: the path had to be /Home/MethodName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified url was wrong. Instead of `url: '/HomeController/MethodName'` I put `url: '/Home/MethodName',`  although my controller name is HomeController

Answer (score 1):

You should rather let the power of the MVC framework take care of rendering the URL. If you change your routing it would possibly mean you have to go around all your html pages and updates similar references. In this way you avoid the above mentioned issue.

Use

```
<%= Html.RenderAction("MethodName", "Home") %>
```

Etc

```
function(id) {
    alert("here");
    $.ajax({
        url: <%= Html.RenderAction("MethodName", "Home") %>,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(data){
             alert('Sucess ' + data);      
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your made a formatting mistake. This `url` string property is not correclty closed. You are also missing a comma at the end of the `data` property.

```
function(id)
 alert("here");
 $.ajax({
   url: '/HomeController/MethodName', // last single quote was missing 
   data: { id: id }, // comma was missing
   success: function(data){
    alert('Sucess ' + data);      
  }
 });
```

Comment: my bad. typo error in this post. My code has no typos but does not still work